# Create Planner Plan

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, microsoft-planner

I tried creating a plan for the existing group using Microsoft Graph Explorer, it was created successfully. Again I tried to create an another plan for the same group it threw me an error saying "MaximumPlannerPlans".

But I used the same code which I tried in the Microsoft Graph Explorer, in my SPFx webpart using **GraphHttpClient** for creating multiple plans, it is allowing me to create multiple plans for the same MS Group. Is it a bug or an expected behavior? If it is an expected behavior then why it is not allowing me to create multiple plans in the Microsoft Graph Explorer?

I am using same user login for the both SPFx webpart and Microsoft Graph Explorer which has an owner access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this user voice, this is requested feature once comes in GA you might be able to create multiple planner for a group.

https://planner.uservoice.com/forums/330525-microsoft-planner-feedback-forum/suggestions/19086499-allow-multiple-plans-per-group

Comment: You are right. MS is working on this part , due to that I am getting this behavior. Thank you for your response.